# on_member_ban event won't work on my cog | discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make it so this event updates the bans number in my json file but i don't get why it won't work, i tried adding print functions to see if the code stopped somewhere and turns out it went all the way through, i also tried making it add a new value in the dictionary inside the json file but that too did not work. Here is a picture of the file locations if needed. Please help me.
It does not show any errors when i run it.

[image]

```
infractionsPath = '././data/infractions.json'
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_ban(self, guild, user):
    bans = await guild.bans()
    banned_users = 0
    for _ in bans:
        banned_users += 1

    guildID = str(guild.id)
    with open(infractionsPath, 'r') as infractionsFile:
        infractions = json.load(infractionsFile)
    infractions[guildID]['bans'] = banned_users
```

Comment: Try passing in member as a parameter instead of user

Comment: on_member_ban doesn't exist...

Comment: @Mikey if it doesn't exist then why is it on the documents though? I was searching for events related to members getting banned and found this
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ban#discord.on_member_ban

Comment: That's my fault, I was thinking of on_member_kick.

Comment: And do you ever dump the json back into the file? That appears to be what the issue is. I see you editing the JSON data but never actually putting it back into the file.